# Convergence of $\int_a^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{x^p\ln ^qx}dx}\,\,\left( a>1 \right) $

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

How to discuss convergence and divergence?

For $p=1$，I use Newton Leibniz and I know for $q=1$,the integral is divergent.

But when $p <1$，how can I calculate the  divergence of integral?

Comment: If $q \leq 0$, then it's easy to show the limit is $\infty$.  If $q > 0$, have you tried L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 0):

With the notation of asymptotic analysis, it well-known that for any $\alpha,\beta >0$, one has
$$\ln ^\alpha x=o(x^\beta).$$
Can you take it from there?